# UWP application Client Machine System Requirements

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

Helo,

I am developing **UWP Application**.
Trying to install build (by **Side loading**) in various systems.
All systems are windows 10 only, but having different processors. Some systems supporting with **Debug mode** generated builds and some systems supporting with **Release mode** generated builds. I am unable to track this issue. Why can't single mode build (whether it may be Debug or Release mode) supporting for all windows 10 systems. Can any one tell me what are the client system requirements for installing and working with **UWP** applicatiton.

Below is my client machine system specifications

[image]

And I have generated build in **Release mode** by selecting both 64 and 32 bit, after side loading I got files like below

[image]

Application installing successfully, but when i am trying to open it's **getting crash.**

I have observed one change In Client Machine.
Marked one getting extra in Packages folder.

[image]

I have verified windows log, it's showing below error.

Activation of app fb23829-a660-4c2e-88df-bc3c735654f7_a2ct2483cqfyg!App failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Comment: Make up your mind, it's WPF or UWP?

Comment: Sorry It's UWP.

Comment: First of all check if OSes have Developer Mode set to OFF, then check the architecture to which you deploy your package. Is it x64 or x86. Maybe your Debug is x64 and  x84 is Release to that 32bit processors cannot open up the Debug version which is compiled on x64. Give us more details.

Comment: I have attached some screen shots, please see my updated question once. @m.rogalski

Comment: Can you check up what's causing that crash? Maybe you can check that in event log or make up your log system?

Comment: In system log got this message.... Activation of app fb23829-a660-4c2e-88df-bc3c735654f7_a2ct2483cqfyg!App failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Comment: Do all Devices have the same *version* of windows 10 installed ?

Comment: Yes , all are windows 10. @Pratyay

Comment: I have updated my question , Could you please verify it. @Pratyay

Comment: They all run Windows 10, but maybe different build. For sure check also build number: Win+R and write "winver" + enter and compare them.

Comment: working machine and non working machine  are having same OS Build. But having different processors. problem is there in i3 processor

Answer (score 0):

After so many trails I came to know that if target machine having **i3 processor** then at the time of generating the build we should select only one type i.e., either it may be **32 bit or 64 bit**. if we select both then application will Crash.